# C# How to use Linq on an XmlAttributeCollection within another Linq statement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmlnode, xmlattributecollection

I have an XML element with subelements like so:

```
<Groups>
    <Group1 name="first" value="1" />
    <Group2 value="2" name="second" />
    <Group3 value="3" />
</Groups>
```

I'm using an already existing method `MyMethod()` to fetch the `Groups` element which returns an `XmlNodeList` object which I cast to an `XmlNode`. After that I want to use a Linq statement to fetch only those groups which have a `name` attribute in them and store those names in a list of strings.

In the code snippet below I'm trying to check if the first attribute's name of an XML node equals `"name"`but it is possible that the `"name"` attribute isn't always the first one. Could you please help me out here and tell me how to use another Linq statement on `Attributes` property below? `Attributes` property is of type [XmlAttributeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattributecollection(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
List<string> result = MyMethod().Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Where(node => node.Attributes[0].Name == "name")
    .Select(node => node.Attributes[0].Value).ToList();
```

EDIT:
I managed to find a solution using the built in method `GetNamedItem`:

```
List<string> result = MyMethod().Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Where(node => node.Attributes?.GetNamedItem("name") != null)
    .Select(node => node.Attributes?.GetNamedItem("name").Value).ToList();
```

Comment: You can try something like this:
var groups = groups.Where(c => c.Elements().Count(b => b.Attribute("name") != null) > 0);
Missing only the condition on list of strings value.
Can you give me an example of list of string value?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about that:

```
List<string> result = MyMethod().Cast<XmlNode>()
    .SelectMany(node => node.Attributes).Where(a => a.Name == "name");
```

Should match your goal to got the object with the specific name, the full code become:

```
List<string> result = MyMethod().Cast<XmlNode>()
        .SelectMany(node => node.Attributes).Where(a => a.Name == "name")
        .Select(a=> a.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Key method for your question is extension method `.SelectMany` which return flattened collection from collection of collections.

As alternative you can use LINQ to XML (sounds like right tool for the job ;))

```
var document = XDocument.Load("pathToXmlFile");

// Here you can use more complex logic of "MyMehthod" 
var allGroups = document.Descendants("Groups");

var names = allGroups.SelectMany(groups => groups.Elements())
                     .Where(group => group.Attribute("name"))
                     .Where(attribute => attribute != null)
                     .Select(attribute => attribute.Value)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Unfortunately I cannot modify `MyMethod()` because it's used in several places. But I managed to find another solution using the `GetNamedItem("name")` built in method.